# How can we automatically transition Epic Jiras based on the transitions of underlying Jiras?

Tags: jira

We are keeping track of our software development and engineering components in Jira by having Epics to contain all of the Jiras required for a deliverable.

We would like to have our Epics transition automatically, based on some simple rules applied to the transitions of the underlying Jiras.

For example, the first underlying Jira that moves to "in-progress", should automatically transition the parent Epic to "in-progress"; and the last Jira that moves to "done" should automatically transition the Epic to "done".

Is there any way to set up triggers to automatically transition Epics based on the transitions of underlying Jiras?

Answer (score 1):

I think [this link](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Marketplace-Apps-Integrations/Change-Epic-status-based-on-some-or-all-linked-issues-statuses/qaq-p/655436) on the Atlassian Community forum may be what you're trying to do.